# More input and one output issue in Keras

Tags: python, merge, keras, keras-layer

```
self.embed = Sequential([Embedding(9488, output_dim=512,input_length=14),
                                Activation('relu'),
                                    Dropout(0.5)], name='embed.0')

self.fc_embed = Sequential([Dense(512, input_shape=(10,2048)),
                                    Activation('relu'),
                                    Dropout(0.5)], name='fc_embed.0')

inputs_bedding = Input(shape=(10,))
xt = self.embed(inputs_bedding)

input_feats = Input(shape=(10,2048))
fc_feats = self.fc_embed(input_feats)

fc_feats_new = K.reshape(fc_feats, [fc_feats.shape[1], fc_feats.shape[2]])
xt_new = K.reshape(xt, [xt.shape[1], xt.shape[2]])

 prev_h = state[0][-1] (shape is (10,512))
 att_lstm_input = Concatenate([prev_h, fc_feats_new, xt_new], axis=1)
 lstm, h_att, c_att = LSTM(units=512, name='core.att_lstm', return_state=True)(att_lstm_input)
 model = Model([input_feats, inputs_att, inputs_bedding], lstm)
 model.summary()
```

This is the error I get:

```
File "copy_eval.py", line 165, in <module>
model1 = TopDownModel.forward(fc_feats, att_feats, seq, att_masks)
```

File "/home/ubuntu/misc/customize_keras.py", line 127, in forward
    lstm, h_att, c_att = LSTM(units=512, name='core.att_lstm', return_state=True)(att_lstm_input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 500, in **call**
    return super(RNN, self).**call**(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 575, in **call**
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 448, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '
ValueError: Layer core.att_lstm was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: . Full input: []. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

For more input, how to merge them into one output?

Comment: Please include the full traceback error, as it points in which line it is producing an error.

Comment: Thank you,  Matias. Updated the full error.

Comment: Use the layer [Concatenate](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate) instead of the backend operation [concatenate](https://keras.io/backend/#concatenate), or wrap [concatenate](https://keras.io/backend/#concatenate) within a [Lambda layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda).

Comment: Thank you, rvinas. What I want to do is to make it as an input for LSTM. Just updated the error. Please help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate should be used as a layer, like this:

```
att_lstm_input = Concatenate(axis=1)([prev_h, fc_feats_new, xt_new])
```

Comment: Thank you, Matias. After I tried to put it into lstm, self.att_lstm(att_lstm_input), got another error, ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer core.att_lstm: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2.

Comment: @user10282036 This is a different problem, means you aren't giving the right input to train the network.

Comment: Thank you,  Matias.